# Unpredictable behaviour of BEFORE INSERT trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am using MySQL 5.1 to write a Before Insert trigger. For this I want to check the `receipt_no` column and increment `version_no` if `receipt_no` is already in the table.

And I presume if no rows are placed using `SELECT INTO` this trigger fails which is what I want so the table which has `default 0` default value on the column comes through.

But the version no seems to get duplicated. What seems like the problem here?

Table layout is of the form:

`id - auto incr primary key

receipt_no - unique constraint  |

version_no - unique constraint  |

other unrelevant column`

```
CREATE TRIGGER `increment_version` BEFORE INSERT ON `my_table` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

       DECLARE version INTEGER;

       SELECT version_no INTO version FROM my_table WHERE receipt_no = NEW.receipt_no LIMIT 1;

       SET NEW.version_no = version + 1;

END
```

Comment: you should have a check for IF version IS NOT NULL THEN END IF ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no record, then the query returns null into `version`, and NULL + 1 gives NULL.
You need to check whether `version` is null or not null.
Also use MAX in the query, because you need to retrieve a greatest version number.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `increment_version` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `my_table` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   DECLARE version INTEGER;

   SELECT max(version_no) INTO version FROM my_table 
   WHERE receipt_no = NEW.receipt_no 
   ;
   IF version IS NOT NULL THEN
     SET NEW.version_no = version + 1;
   END IF;
END
```

see this demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b82c34/1

Comment: Thanks for your response. Was assuming that trigger throw error and exits in case of no rows. Good to know about the null.